# Application of Panjer recursion scheme

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, applications

I'm writing my bachelor (the argument is the Compound Poisson Process applied to insurance) and I need an example to complete it.

I need an application of Panjer recursion scheme (for example something like stop-loss reinsurance) but I need some examples with numbers and graph.

Someine can help me?

Comment: The wiki article on [Panjer recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panjer_recursion) has a graph as well as link to VoseSoftware online docs.

Comment: You may ask it on quant.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

seems like magazine "Insurance Mathematics and Economics" has relevant topics

take a look at amazon list for "[Insurance Mathematics and Economics](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=Insurance%20Mathematics%20and%20Economics&x=0&y=0)" keyword search.